# my bash may does recognize lowercase and uppercase are same

Tags: bash, shell, command

```sh
mv readme.md README.md
```

then I getting message 
`'readme.md' and 'README.md' are the same file`

why my ubuntu did not recognize lowercase and uppercase..?

`cd` it works well but, for example i wanna move src directory,

```sh
CD src
```

then i getting message 
`bash: CD: command not found`

without this kind of case, my bash works well..

env ubuntu 18.04
tell me about if get more my infomation to solve prob.

Comment: Try `diskutil list` on the macOS host to see if you are running case-insensitive HFS+ as filesystem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be using the NTFS or VFAT fileystem, which are case insensitive. See this answer on Superuser: https://superuser.com/a/431346.

But bash is case sensitive in all cases, that's why `CD` is an unkown command.

As mentioned in the comments, OP is using OSX as host while running Ubuntu inside a Docker Container. Docker uses the [osfx](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/osxfs/) filesystem on OSX.

The Docker documentation says this:

> With Docker Desktop for Mac, **file systems operate in containers in the
>   same way as they operate in macOS**. If a file system on macOS is
>   case-insensitive, that behavior is shared by any bind mount from macOS
>   into a container.

And also this:

> On macOS Sierra and lower, the default file system is HFS+. On macOS
>   High Sierra, the default file system is APFS. **Both are
>   case-insensitive by default** but available in case-sensitive and
>   case-insensitive variants.

So the solution to your problem is to enable case sensitivity for your host OS to enable it for your Docker VMs.

Comment: as i know, NTFS and VFAT are used Windows system right?
but  I use Macbook and the ubuntu that I using is on docker.
also ~/.inputrc file isn’t exists.

Comment: wow.. very kind explanation..! 
I guessing that This Problem is related to file system 
so, I checked  whether my Mac system in-sensitive or not. The result is that my Mac is in-sensitive. but, 
command ‘mv readme.md README.md’ is works. also if ‘a’ named file exists, ‘vi A’ command is also works..
thanks to your kind answer, I could learn linux Thank you bro!